# Meteor.js with D3

Tags: d3.js, meteor

I'm a newbie for Meteor.js but however I need to make some chart like http://nvd3.org/examples/pie.html. Bu I have no idea to render data on my html page.

```
  Pie = new Meteor.Collection("pie");

  if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.chart.created = function(){ //not sure for template style.
        _.defer(function () {

            Deps.autorun(function () {
                pp = Pie.find({}, {fields: {_id: 0}});
                exampleData = _.toArray(pp);
                console.log(exampleData);
                //Regular pie chart example
                nv.addGraph(function() {
                  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
                      .showLabels(true);

                    d3.select("#chart svg")
                        .datum(exampleData)
                        .transition().duration(350)
                        .call(chart);

                  return chart;
                });

                //Donut chart example
                nv.addGraph(function() {
                  var chart = nv.models.pieChart()
                      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
                      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
                      .showLabels(true)     //Display pie labels
                      .labelThreshold(.05)  //Configure the minimum     slice size for labels to show up
                      .labelType("percent") //Configure what type of   data to show in the label. Can be "key", "value" or "percent"
                      .donut(true)          //Turn on Donut mode. Makes pie chart look tasty!
                      .donutRatio(0.35)     //Configure how big you want the donut hole size to be.
                      ;

                    d3.select("#chart2 svg")
                        .datum(exampleData)
                        .transition().duration(350)
                        .call(chart);

                  return chart;
                });
            });
        });
    }

}

  if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    if(Pie.find().count() === 0) {
        var data = [
              { 
                "label": "One",
                "value" : 29.765957771107
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Two",
                "value" : 0
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Three",
                "value" : 32.807804682612
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Four",
                "value" : 196.45946739256
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Five",
                "value" : 0.19434030906893
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Six",
                "value" : 98.079782601442
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Seven",
                "value" : 13.925743130903
              } , 
              { 
                "label": "Eight",
                "value" : 5.1387322875705
              }
            ];

        for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++){
            Pie.insert({
                label: data[i].label,
                value: data[i].value
            });
        }
    }

  });
  }
```

d3.html

```
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>d3</title>

 </head>

 <body>
  {{> chart}}
 </body>

 <template name="chart">
 <div width="500" height="500">
 <svg id="chart"></svg>
 <svg id="chart2"></svg>
 </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Ok now I can solve my problem thank a lot for helping from imslavko.

Comment: This the way for solving. HTML page <div id="chart"><svg></svg></div> and d3.js jus change Template.chart.created to be Template.chart.rendered. For the last one at d3.css just add #chart svg {height: 400px;} And done

Answer (score 4):

As tested with Meteor both prior to Blaze and with Blaze: it is enough to start your `Deps.autorun` in the `rendered` callback of the template and just put your d3 drawing code there.

In Meteor prior to v.0.8.0, you would need to wrap the svg part into `#constant` region but once you use Blaze, it is not necessary.

An alternative is to draw everything once in `rendered` callback and then start `observeChanges` and keep your d3 view-model up to date.

I have a simple example here: https://github.com/Slava/d3-meteor-basic

Comment: Thank you for your helping. I spend many hours for solving this problem. If I stuck in anywhere from my code I will ask you again.

Comment: no, don't ask me again. ask a separate question on stackoverflow

Comment: I try to run your code with blaze engine but it not working. Note I run it on Meteor version 0.8.1.1. So could you solve them.

Comment: I cloned your example from https://github.com/Slava/d3-meteor-basic, but when I run it I just get a completely blank browser window.  Inspect element shows that there is a blank 500x500 box, but that's it.  Also, your example makes use of the #constant region which you state here is no longer necessary.

Comment: @JonCrowell it uses #constant because the repo was created before the newer rendering engine

Comment: @imslavko ok, I've submitted a pull request to update the code by removing the #constant.  Still gives a completely blank browser window, though.

Comment: If your database is empty, how did you expect to see anything on the screen?

Comment: @imslavko because other d3 + meteor examples work for me and also provide brief Readme files that orient me with the broad outlines of what is going on.

Comment: @JonCrowell then link them here in a new answer, share it with people